# Access Toggle Switch State in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm making a calculator, where on a single screen there are multiple Switches (using react-native Switch). Depending on which Switches are enabled or disabled, I want to write an if/else statement. In my if/else statement I want to access the value of the Switch, whether it is turned on or off. The Facebook React Native Switch page does not make it clear to em how I use the switch and pass information around.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Switch,
  TextInput,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';



export class TimiCalculator extends Component {


constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { SwitchValue: false };
}

render() {
  return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
    <Switch 
      onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({SwitchValue: value})}
      value={this.state.SwitchValue} />
  </View>

    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonCalculate} onPress={this.showCalculation}>
    <Text style={styles.title}> Calculate </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

  </View>
  );
}

showCalculation() {

if (ACCESS_STATE_OF_TOGGLE_SWITCH_HERE == true) {
*DO THIS
} else {
*DO THIS INSTEAD
}

Alert.alert('Your output is' + answer)
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to read https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html since state is the very basics of React development. In this case you did not know how to refer state.

Here is the most short and cleaniest answer

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Switch,
} from 'react-native';

export class TimiCalculator extends Component {
  state = {isSwitchOn: false}

  showCalculation = () => {
    if (this.state.isSwitchOn) {
      // do something
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Switch 
          onValueChange={isSwitchOn => this.setState({isSwitchOn})}
          value={this.state.isSwitchOn} 
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonCalculate} onPress={this.showCalculation}>
          <Text style={styles.title}> Calculate </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right, I needed to know how to refer state. Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear. Also select this answer correct so other people who have same problem as you can get help fast :)

Comment: not working switch is getting on and then turning off automatically...(both on ios and android)....

Answer (score 1):

```
showCalculation() {

if (this.state. SwitchValue == true) {
//do here what you want 
this.setState({SwitchValue:false});
} else {

this.setState({SwitchValue: true});

}
```

i will suggest you to use look at this code if you want to implement calculator .

[here](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/react-native-tutorial-part-3-developing-a-calculator)